# Flex Spark PNG Image with Transparency acting as button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a PNG image that has some transparency it is a 20px x 20px png image of an X.  Given the shape of the X the hit state is odd since it gets interpreted as transparent.  How do you make the whole area 20px x 20px clickable?

```
<s:Image id="closeOut" y="10" source="@Embed('/assets/png/X.png')" click="this.visible=false"/>
```

If you hover over where ever there isn't the X, left and right mostly it isn't clickable.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helped you out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the image in a group of 20x20px and add the mouse event on the group and not on the image.

```
<s:Group y="10" width="20" height="20" click="this.visible=false">
      //Your image here
</s:Group>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I increase the width and height of the s:Group, does it make it more forgiving to the user?  Larger hit area?

Comment: Ideally, and I recommend it, you should cut a larger image if that is your need. A group may not catch events in transparent areas, unless you use the mouseEnabledWhereTransparent property and set it to true. If you are going with a larger group and the same size image I would recommend you set the horizontalCenter and the verticalCenter to 0 for the image and keep the width and height of the image as 20px so that it comes in the center of your group, or leave it as per your requirement. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hope my comments have answered your question and your problem is solved. Please accept the answer, or please let me know in case you have any further questions. Thanks.